# Optional type'Bool' cannot be used as boolean

Tags: xcode, swift

```
var plays = Dictionary<Int,Int>()
var done = false
var aiDeciding = false

if  (!plays[sender.tag] && !aiDeciding && !done){
     self.setImageForSpot(sender.tag, player:1)
```

> this line says Optional type'Bool' cannot be used as a boolean; test
>   for '!nil=' instead.  I did what it said, but it made it even worse.

```
     checkForWin()
     aiTurn()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you check plays[sender.tag] this could return an Int or nil.  It is not a bool.  So try:

```
var plays = Dictionary<Int,Int>() 
var done = false
var aiDeciding = false

if  ((plays[sender.tag] == nil) && !aiDeciding && !done){
    self.setImageForSpot(sender.tag, player:1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your working if statement:

```
if (plays[sender.tag] != nil) && !aiDeciding && !done{

}
```

In your code you did `!plays[sender.tag]` which doesn't return bool but it returns `Int` values because you declared a `dictionary` which have `Int` keys and values.

so you need to check if that is nil or not and if it isn't nil you can proceed.